# Data Storage / Querying on the Mac

Tags: macos, cocoa, accounting

I am studying Cocoa. I have gotten familiar with the basics. I would like to know what things must I focus on to be able to write an accounting software.
SQL allows queries to data in Windows. What is done in Mac OS for managing data and retrieving desired filtered information from the database?

Answer (score 4):

Look up the Core Data tutorial.  Core data provides a persistent data store, with multiple choices of underlying implementation, including SQLite.